# Unity3d how can i program my game?

Tags: game-engine, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am creating an Android 2d game in unity3d game engine. I've created an endless map and a continuously moving ball is my character. I've got some pits digged on my platform. If the user clicks anywhere on the screen, the ball will bounce. Now, if the ball accidently fell into the pits, I want the game to stop(meaning the game has failed) and restart from the beginning.
Can anyone pls tell me the script or code I've to use for the game to restart ????
Any help would be great!!!!

Comment: This is really broad and opinion-soliciting, with no "right" answer (so... off-topic for StackOverflow). Not sure what you're expecting regarding help (and there's no need to post comments to your own question asking for help, especially one minute after posting your question - nobody is being paid to scramble to answer you). As to the question itself: you've shown zero code, so anything posted would be based on... nothing to do with your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fill the Pits with [Box Collidiers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BoxCollider.html) wich are marked as Triggers.

Then you write a Script with

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
if(other.gameobject.tag == "Player")
//do something
}
```

[Doku OnTrigger Enter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html)

That should do the Job

Comment: Thanks Dropye for your efficient answer